# Contract extension - when to give an answer

Tags: contractors, contract-extension

Some background:

- I'm working as a contractor at a consulting company.
- Contract ends in a month and I was offered an extension.
- I want to move on because I'm not really enjoying the work.

I don't want to reject the extension before I found something else. My contract doesn't specify how much notice I have to go. What's the best strategy to postpone giving them an answer for as long as possible? What are the usual practices in such situations?

Comment: Have you tried asking what their timeframe is for receiving an answer? How long is the extension for? If it's not an insufferable length of time, you could accept the attention until something better comes along

Comment: "I don't want to reject the extension before I found something else" - Great, so do that. Go actively look for something else. You can even ask them to take a few weeks off as personal time after this month - go spend that time actively looking for a job you'll love. One thing I wouldn't do is lie and "postpone giving them an answer for as long as possible".

Answer (score 1):

A couple of suggestions based on the fact that you want to move on;

Find out your notice period (if applicable).
Agree a fixed day to provide your answer, sooner the better.

Reasoning - secure where you are before considering moving on somewhere else.

Ultimately there is no reason why you cannot find another contract when in employment, simply have phone interviews, interviews at the end of the day or beginning instead.  This is a commonly done thing nowadays and can in fact impress the future employer knowing that you seem to take your commitment to your current role seriously.

The sooner you get a new role the sooner you are out of where you don't want to be.